# Android Studio Instant Run makes HTTPS handshake fail

Tags: android, https, android-instant-run

I am using **Android Studio 2.2.2** to develop my project.And I use HTTPS in my project to get data from server.But when I open the **Instant Run** options,the HTTPS fails and saying "https handshake fail".After I turn off Instant Run and reinstall my app,it turns out to be OK again.Does anyone ever got into similar situation?Or can someone tells me why **Instant Run** has some effect on **HTTPS**?

Comment: It shouldn't have any effect at all and in my experience it doesn't.  Try cleaning and rebuilding the project. But without any more information it will be difficult to give more specific advice.

Comment: This doesn't shows up every time I send a https request.But once it comes up,all https keeps failing,even I rerun it with Instant Run on.But after I turn instant run off and reinstall app,the situation disappear.I will apply the exception info when it comes up next time.

Comment: You might also want to test it on a different device, or using your data connection instead of WiFi. The problem might actually be the fault of the device or the network you are using.